# RequestMapping with multiple patterns

Tags: spring

I have a controller with two methods. One to delete a user another to remove a user from a role.

```
    @Controller
    @RequestMapping(value="/rest/users/**")
    public class UsersCtrlr {

        @RequestMapping(value="/{username:.+}", method=RequestMethod.DELETE)
        public @ResponseBody HttpStatusDoc deleteUser(HttpServletRequest req, @PathVariable String username) {
         ...
        }

        @RequestMapping(value="/{username:.+}/roles/{role:.+}", method=RequestMethod.DELETE)
        public @ResponseBody HttpStatusDoc deleteUserRole(HttpServletRequest req, @PathVariable String username, @PathVariable String role) {
         ...
        }
    }
```

My front end makes a jquery ajax call with a url as follows:

```
/rest/users/jdoe@foo.com/roles/some_role
```

This uri is being mapped to the deleteUser method with a `username` equal to `some_role`

I'm trying to get the uri to map to the deleteUserRole and have the `username` set to `jdoe@foo.com` and `role` set to `some_role`.

Why won't the uri map to the deleteUserRole?
Does it have something to do with the regular expressions in the RequestMappings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is likely because of `**` in your class @RequestMapping annotation , your mapping for `deleteUser` will be `/rest/users/**/{username:.+}` and for `deleteUserRole` will be `/rest/users/**/{username:.+}/roles/{role:.+}` and the first one will match up to `/rest/users/jdoe@foo.com/roles/some_role` pattern. It should work if `**` is removed from the class @RequestMapping annotation

Comment: Thanks. Works like a charm. Changed the class @RequestMapping annotion to `@RequestMapping(value="/rest/users")`